# Creating an App for Sharepoint using Dev, AngularJS and RestAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I'm needing to create a sharepoint app that lists the items selected in the code. I created the code in napa and downloaded it to visual studio to edit better.

I got the following error in chrome console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token."

This code is inside the default.aspx created by Napa:

```
    <div ng-app>
        <b>AngularJS + Sharepoint!</b>
        <div ng-controller="MyController" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-repeat="p in Products">
                Product Name: {{p.ProductName}} <br />
                Rate: Rs. {{p.ProductRate}} <br />
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>    
        function MyController($scope) {
            $scope.loadREST = function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSONP",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var newData = [];
                        jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
                            newData.push({ ProductName: value.ProductName, ProductRate: value.ProductRate});
                        });
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.Products = newData;
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //alert(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
                        alert("erro de conexão");
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.loadREST();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: When you click on the error in chrome it should take you to the relevant javascript file with the error. Where does that take you?

Comment: Chrome don't show any relevant code. Only the error.

Comment: I've seen this before when the data returned by an ajax call has an error. Can you use chrome's network tab to inspect the response of the ajax request and post the results here?

Comment: I never do this so what I have to paste here? Header, Preview, Response or Timing?

Comment: Post the response section

Comment: Chrome is not easy to use to expose the response body. I really prefer Firefox + Firebug. Much cleaner :-) But it's definitively the perfect way to see which error the server returns.

Comment: Is that you want to see: `{"d":{"GetContextWebInformation":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.ContextWebInformation"},"FormDigestTimeoutSeconds":1800,"FormDigestValue":"0xD6A16E75310904DA7BCFB8098312976551E9EBEF9830636BF625A8A23C2ECEDEF6ED77B9BA7D42C32F6924DA39745AAE573302E842668DF26BFBB55F02EB4076,21 Feb 2014 13:26:10 -0000","LibraryVersion":"16.0.2524.1216","SiteFullUrl":"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev","SupportedSchemaVersions":{"results":["14.0.0.0","15.0.0.0"]},"WebFullUrl":"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/RestTest"}}}`